# customising line styles in Python using vlines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some vertical lines in Python using vlines:

```
for i in range(100):
    plt.vlines(xvalues[i],0,20,linestyles='-',colors='r')
```

But I would ideally like to customise the style of the line. I have seen [instructions](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/dash_control.html) about how to customise, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my vlines example.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides the predefined linestyles you can directly specify offset and onoffseq (see e.g. [LineCollection](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection))

So just change your code to

```py
for i in range(3):
    l=plt.vlines(i,0,20,linestyles=[(0,(9,3,4,4))],colors='r')
```

[image]
here, linestyles requires a list with the (offset, onoffseq) tuple, in the present case: offset 0, 9 points on, 3 points off, 4 points on, 4 points off.

Btw.:
It is more pythonic to do `for i in xvalues: print i` instead of the index based approach `for i in range(100): print xvalues[i]`

Comment: The `[(0, (...))]` syntax is what does it! `[]` for possibly multiple styles, then `(0, (...))` for the custom line style.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [documentation for `vlines`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=vlines#matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines).

The possible values for `linestyles` are given as:

> linestyles : [‘solid’ | ‘dashed’ | ‘dashdot’ | ‘dotted’], optional